# "Recent Files" in Nautilus sometimes doesn't show recent folders

Tags: 14.04, nautilus

I found that "Recent Files" in Nautilus sometimes doesn't show recent modified/created folders, and sometimes does. Is it an error? How can I make it show folders all the time?

Comment: Same problem, ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Same problem, ubuntu 20.04 , Files/nautilus  3.36.3

Comment: Same on Ubuntu 22.04, but for files. The way I create the files seem to affect whether they are listed in the Recent category or not. For instance, a screenshot done via native screenshot app will be displayed, but a capture done via custom tool "gifine" will not.